# Internet Explorer Iframe cookie issue

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe, cookies

I am building an ASP.NET 3.5 application in which I have a page which loads another page in  a different domain in an iframe. Below is the for **Default.aspx** page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="server">
    <iframe src="isite.aspx" runat="server" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto">

    </iframe>
</asp:Content>
```

Below is the iframe page **isite.aspx**:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0; text-align: center;">
        <form id="Form1" name="frmSubmit" action="https://mysite.com/Login.asp"
        method="POST" runat="server">
        <span style="font-family: Arial">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="https://mysite.com/Login.asp" ImageUrl="/ajax-loader.gif" /> Please wait...
    <br />
        </span>
        <input type="hidden" name="txtUserName" size="30" maxlength="50" value="admin"
            onkeypress="Javascript:CheckKeyPress('ID')"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="pwdPassword" size="30" maxlength="25" value="password"
            onkeypress="Javascript:CheckKeyPress('P')"/>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Below is the **isite.aspx.cs** page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "click", "<script language=javascript>document.getElementById('" + ImageButton1.ClientID + "').click();</script>");
    }
```

This works fine in Firefox,Safari and Chrome but it dosent work in IE 7 or 8. In IE it gives me a HTTP 500 error page. After doing some research on it I figured that its a cookie issue in IE and tried the below soutions:

1. Added the following code to the Global.asax:

   `protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)

   {

       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");

   }`
2. Added the following line of code to the Page_Init and Page_Load events

   `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");`

None of these solutions worked for me. What am I missing?

Comment: i have the same issue and hope to find a solution, i just found this old post http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/369240/ie8-will-not-send-third-party-cookies-set-in-another-window-tab   which say that its a bug in IE8 and IE team will solve, when?! i have no idea :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in IE, and none of the online solutions helped me, in my case i forced the user to login again inside the iframe, and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

"p3p" should be in caps like "P3P"